# Selenium Chrome, 'click' action takes infinite time to complete

Tags: ruby, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am performing a click action on an element which is not available in web (chrome) browser.

Expectation is to throw `element not found` exception and fail the test, but selenium driver is waiting indefinitely(more than 10 hours) for the element to load and the test got hanged in middle.

Note: I also set the implicit_time wait for the webdriver as 10 seconds.
If some other element is not found in the web page, driver is throwing the `element not found` exception as expected, but only on clicking an element in the `react.js popup` this scenario happens.

Does any one faced same situation like above?

Application Frontend : react.js

Chrome version : 76.0.3809.100

Chrome driver version : 76.0.3809.68/chromedriver_mac64.zip

The test gets hanged only on the click action. When we try to assert whether the element is `displayed?` we are getting `false` immediately. Changed the code to click on the element only if it is displayed. I this case the scenario doesn't hang.

Literally there is no error message from chrome or selenium or chrome driver.

Comment: This is with ruby but not watir? You should post some code,

Comment: @pguardiario i am just trying to click a button. `driver.find_element(:css,'div button').click`. Only difference i see here is that the button is present in react.js popup.